# Flask - passing an argument to window.location.replace()

Tags: javascript, flask

In a Flask framework, I have a `menu.html`, with a clickable link:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('loading',name=lunch)}}";>{{ lunch }}</a>
```

and this is the corresponding url view:

```
@app.route('/loading/<name>')
def loading(name):
    return render_template('loading.html',
                            name=name)
```

`loading.html` has this script at he bottom:

```
<script> window.location.replace('/lunch/{{name}}'); 
</script>
```

pointing to a final view where a consuming task is being processed:

```
@app.route('/lunch/<name>')
    def (name):
        #(long, consuming task)
        return render_template('lunch.html',
                                name=name)
```

and if a click, for example, on a item link named 'meat', I get a **404**, like so:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2018 16:27:02] "GET /loading?name=meat HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

and not `GET /loading/meat 200`, as expected.

so what is the simplest way of passing correctly the call to `window.location.replace()`in this framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I would use window.location.href = 'path/to/destination'

Since your waiting for and API responce it would go something like this (using promises anyway)

```
fetch(url).then((response) => {
 // do something to the response
}).then(() => {
  window.location.href = '/lunch/{{name}}'
})
```

This will take you to the function your looking use.

For those looking for just redirect you can use the redirect from the flask library. First import the redirect from the library:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, [anything else]
```

Then I'd write the first function like this:

```
@app.route('/loading/<string:name>')
def loading(name):
    return redirect(url_for('name',
                            name=name))
```

This will send you to your function name with the name that was clicked originally. I also think it helps to specify the type when putting a variable in the @app.rout decorator like I did with `<string:name>` or if you had an id `<int:id>`

Comment: I need to render `loading.html`, and `window.location.replace()` is there to be called AFTER such rendering...

Comment: is there a certain amount of time you need to be on loading.html or is it waiting for an event?\

Comment: a fairly long amount of time. basically waiting for api call responses.

Comment: I updated the answer. I see your trying to show a loading page (duh). Well I'd use promises for my api call and tie it in with a promise that sets window.location.href = (where your trying to go)

Comment: it is not working for me. it seems to me that there is a simple syntax problem here, because if I use: `window.location.href('/lunch/meat')`, with meat instead of a variable, it works. it looks like the problem is how to assign meat to 'name' and then pass it.

Comment: yeah I wrote it wrong at first and tried to quickly change it. You're supposed to assign window.location.href. Like window.location.href = '/lunch/{{name}}'

Comment: nope, I still get: `127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2018 18:14:13] "GET /loading?name=meat HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164369/discussion-between-stephen-agwu-and-outkast).